# C multiple files, segmentation fault printing an array

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

I have this code interaction with 2 files, but I am getting a segmentation error in these two functions and I need help figuring out why. `fileA.c` passes an `int**` to a function in `fileB.c`, the `int**` serves as an output parameter because I want to make an int array in `fileB` and have `foo` point to it so I can print it in `fileA`. In `fileB.c`, I make an array, and set the pointer to it.

size and foo are initialized in another function in a main file. It compiles fine, the output though would be (if `size == 10`) :

> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

Segmentation fault

In `fileA.c`:

```
void testPointing(int size, int** foo) {
    initialize(size, foo);
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%d ", (*foo)[i]);
    }
}
```

`fileB.c`:

```
void initialize(int size, int** foo) {
    int* a;
    a = (int*)malloc(size * sizeof(int);
    int i;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    foo = &a;
}
```

I need help fixing and understanding why I am getting a segmentation fault. Whenever I opt to put the loop located in `fileA.c` after
`foo = &a`
in `fileB.c` instead, it compiles and shows a correct output.

Comment: why are you printing a[i]? It is uninitiated memory.

Comment: Also note that it's a [bad idea to cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169), so write the allocation like this: `a = malloc(size * sizeof *a);`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The address returned by `malloc()` is what holds your data, and that's stored in `a`, not `&a`. `&a` is just the address of the local variable `a`.

Also, `foo` is just the local function argument of `initialize()`, not the passed argument of the caller; that's `*foo`. That leaves the caller's `foo` unset, which is why you get a segmentation fault.

So instead of:

```
foo = &a;
```

you need:

```
*foo = a;
```

And the initial call to `testPointing()` should be something like this:

```
int* array;
testPointing(size, &array);
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation, everything works fine now. I understand my errors and the concepts needed to avoid it again, and I can continue to code the rest of my project.